# Contar intervalos en DF dependiente de otra variable

Tags: python

Estoy intentando contar intervalos de una variable, dependiendo de otra variable `dummy` que me indica cada intervalo.

Mi *data* se ve así:

```
dummy counter 
  0      1  
  0      1  
  0      1  
  1      1  
  0      1  
  0      1  
  1      1  
  0      1  
 ...    ...  
  1      1  
  0      1  
  0      1  
 ...    ...
```

Necesito que quede así: (contando en `var2`).

```
 dummy counter 
  0      1  
  0      1  
  0      1  
  1      1  
  0      2  
  0      3  
  1      1  
  0      2  
 ...    ...  
  1      1  
  0      2  
  0      3  
 ...    ...
```

Utilicé un `for` ya, pero tarda demasiado. En casos anteriores similares, he hecho algo como lo siguiente, guiarse por los indices (que hay): (pero no logro hacer que funcione):

```
counter = False
for idx in df.index:
    if counter:
        if df.loc[idx, "var1"] > 0:
            counter = False
        else:
            df.loc[idx, "counter"] += 1
    else:
        if df.loc[idx, "var1"] < 1:
            cambiar_signo = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como lo planteas el problema se reduce a una suma acumulada por intervalos determinados por `dummy`. Las filas que integran cada intervalo las puedes determinar usando una combinación de `pandas.Series.cumsum` y `pandas.Series.groupby`, si aplicamos una suma acumulada a la columna `dummy` obtenemos algo así:

```
>>> df.dummy.cumsum()

0     0
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     2
7     2
8     3
9     3
```

por lo que podemos usar `groupby` sobre `counter` usando el resultado anterior para agrupar.

```
import pandas as pd



df = pd.DataFrame({"dummy":   (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                   "counter": (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                   })

inter = df.dummy.cumsum()
inter_filter = inter > 0      # Descartamos primer intervalo, antes del primer 1 en dummy
df.loc[inter_filter, "counter"] = df.loc[inter_filter, "counter"].groupby(inter).cumsum()
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>     dummy  counter
> 0       0        1
> 1       0        1
> 2       0        1
> 3       1        1
> 4       0        2
> 5       0        3
> 6       1        1
> 7       0        2
> 8       1        1
> 9       0        2
> 10      0        3
> 11      0        4
> 12      0        5
> 13      0        6
> 14      1        1
> 15      0        2
> 16      0        3
> ```

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla! you did it again!